# Probability without the sample space

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

In probability theory one starts a sample space $(\Omega, \mathbb{P})$, where $\Omega$ is a measurable space and $\mathbb P$ is a designated probability measure, and then builds the theory from there:

- Random variables are measurable functions $X\colon \Omega\to \mathcal X$ with the distribution of $X$ given by the pushforward $P_X = X_\sharp \mathbb P$.
- Using random variables it is easy to say what joint probability distribution $P_{XY}$ is, what a random variable $f(X)$ is and so on.
- Then, one can define regular conditional probability via the disintegration theorem.

However, what I dislike here is that there exists this one big sample space $\Omega$ together with a specified probability measure $\mathbb P$ and we always work with some pushfowards of it.

Having such a prespecified object doesn't sound very categorical to me! I would perfectly work with a more axiomatic approach, where the primary objects of interests are probability spaces $(\mathcal X, P_X)$.

For example, for a measurable map $f\colon \mathcal X\to \mathcal Y$ and a measure $P_X$ on $\mathcal X$ the pushforward $f_\sharp P_X$ on $\mathcal Y$ is defined without any reference to $\mathbb P$.
I suppose that the construction of conditional probability can also be defined via Markov kernels, again without invoking $\mathbb P$ at all and the disintegration theorem.

Hence, I'd like to work with *axioms* showing how to manipulate distributions using measurable mappings, without having to define the sample space $(\Omega, \mathbb P)$, which would only provide a particular model of this theory.

I wonder if you could suggest a book or articles which treat probability theory from this perspective (no sample space, but working with probability distributions and Markov kernels directly).

Comment: possibly related: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/245a-notes-5-free-probability/

Comment: Thank you, it's indeed very interesting! I'll keep the question open, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No other than F. W. Lawvere gave a seminar in 1962 on this topic: *The category of probabilistic mappings with applications to stochastic processes, statistics, and pattern recognition*, in which he proposed the Kleisli category of probabilistic mappings.

Since then, the topic has been further investigated by numerous authors.

For example, there are two recent articles on this topic:

- In [1] the authors discuss the relation between the category proposed by  Lawvere and the category of statistical models.
- In [2] the Markov category and synthetic probability and statistics are discussed.

1. Jost, J., Lê, H.V. & Tran, T.D. *Probabilistic morphisms and Bayesian nonparametrics*. [Eur. Phys. J. Plus 136, 441, 2021](https://doi.org/10.1140/epjp/s13360-021-01427-7).
2. Tobias Fritz, *A synthetic approach to Markov kernels, conditional independence and theorems on sufficient statistics*, [Advances in Mathematics, Volume 370, 2020](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2020.107239).